# is there a way in JavaScript to use string+variable as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did try to do this (with jQuery):

```
type = (blabla == blublu)? 'category':'regular';
(type+'Name').val('...');
```

this is the console response:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object categoryName has no method 'val'

although they actually exist...

so how can I make it work??

### edit:

this is the full function:

```
var type = (1 == 1)?'something':'blabla';

var somethingName = $('#somethingName');
var blablaName = $('#blablaName');
more variables like this..

function itemMode(mode, inputValue){
  inputValue = (typeof inputValue !== 'undefined')? inputValue:'';
  var functionName = null;
  switch(mode){
  case 'open':
    btnValue = 'something';
    functionName = editCategory; // this need to be from type to
    openItem = true;
    break;
  case 'close':
    btnValue = 'something';
    functionName = addCategory; // this need to be from type to
    openItem = false;
    break;
  default:
    return false;
  }
  (type+'Name').val(inputValue);
  $('#btn'+type.capitalize()).off('click').val(btnValue).click(functionName);
  (type+'Name').off('keypress').keypress(function(e){enterPress(e,functionName);});
}
```

i try (type+'Name') to crate reference to an existing var or object.

Comment: can you present your actual full jQuery code? And explain what exactly you want to get from where?

Comment: Assuming `categoryName` for example is an ID attribute, you would go `$('#' + type + 'Name')`.

Comment: Global variables are properties of the window object: `window["foo"+"bar"]`

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to deal with CSS selectors or Javascript variables.

Comment: ok i will edit the question...

Comment: More context in the question is good, but you've still not made it clear what you expect to refer to with `(type+'Name')`.

Comment: no i won't want to say CSS selector

Comment: (type+'Name') to crate reference to an existing var or object.

Comment: So you want to reference a javascript variable (or object) called `somethingName` or `blablaName` (as in your example)?  But you then use it as a jQuery object and try to add and remove event handlers.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I try to do

Comment: It can only be a javascript variable/object *or* a jQuery object.  In your code you treat it as both.  My answer, below, will show you how to reference a javscript variable/object by name, but I don't understand why you're then trying to use jQuery methods on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Variable" Variables in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are created as properties of the window object, so if they are global you can do this...

```
window[type + "Name"]
```

Since you want to refer to a "cached" jQuery object, use the following...

```
(window[type + "Name"]).val("123");
```

For example, if you've cached a jQuery object like this...

```
var sumVar = $('#sumid');
```

You can refer to it directly like this...

```
sumVar.val("123");
```

Or you can refer to it using a variable as the name, like this...

```
var varName = "sumVar";

(window[varName]).val("123");
```

Here's a modified version of the script you posted above...

```
var type = (1 == 1)?'something':'blabla';

window.somethingName = $('#somethingName');
window.blablaName = $('#blablaName');

function itemMode(mode, inputValue){
    inputValue = (typeof inputValue !== 'undefined')? inputValue:'';
    var functionName = null;
    switch(mode){
        case 'open':
            btnValue = 'something';
            functionName = editCategory; // this need to be from type to
            openItem = true;
            break;
        case 'close':
            btnValue = 'something';
            functionName = addCategory; // this need to be from type to
            openItem = false;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    (window[type + 'Name']).val(inputValue);

    $('#btn' + type.capitalize()).off('click').val(btnValue).click(functionName);

    (window[type + 'Name']).off('keypress').keypress(function(e){enterPress(e,functionName);});
}
```

Comment: it just i dont want to do this $('#sumid') in the function because i did it 2 lins before the function declared so i did $('#sumId') into sumVar and when i do sumVar.jQuerystuff() it work but when i try to expand my function to more same suff i need it to be variable

Comment: I learned Programming not to repeat things twice, this is my goal

Comment: Okay, I've updated the answer and I *think* it will help more.

Comment: If you just want to refer to a cached jQuery object then just use the variable.  `var $body = $("body"); $body.hide();` - for example.

Comment: I try my best but i do `var sumVar = 123` and `console.log(sumVar);`
return 123 and `console.log(window[sumVar]);` return undefined

Comment: Please check the code I just posted, with changes to your original script.  I put `window.` before the 2 variable declarations, and then reference them later using `window[...]`.  Other than that I've not changed anything.

Comment: @GoDLighT This is the expected behaviour since `window[sumVar]` is the same as `window[123]`, and there is no variable named "123". To get the value of the variable "sumVar" you have to do that : `window['sumVar']`.

Comment: In that example you just posted, `window[sumVar]` will look for a property of the `window` object called "123", as that is the value of `sumVar`.  You should have done `window["sumVar"]` as you're trying to reference a variable by name.

Comment: k got it i wil try it

Comment: i lost the jQuery object console say: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'val' `

Comment: in `(window[type + 'Name']).val(inputValue);` it return the corrent input elemet but not jQuery object

Comment: Both `somethingName` and `blablaName` are jQuery objects, so it must not be referencing one of them, or you're not doing it as in the script above.  Open the console and type `window["somethingName"]` and then `window["blablaName"]` and see what is returned for each

Comment: When I give up on the `var` in `var sumVar = $('sumId')` it return the object but with the `var` it return only html element

Comment: Can you do what I asked in the previous comment, to debug the issue you've got with the script?

Comment: my script is diffrent from the exmple so i try to do 3 new lines to try your solution, 1 `var sumVar = $('input')` 2 `console.log(window['sumvar'])` 3 `console.log(sumvar)` and i put it next to where it shuld be in the code within functions so when i use `var` the varible is not global and he save only the corrent element but not the jQuery object

Comment: Use `window.sumVar = $("input");` and then refer to is as `(window["sumVar"])` - be careful of case.  Your comment above shows different cases for the examples

Comment: No problem - glad we got there in the end :)

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is not with the concatenation. That works fine. You concatenate `type` with `'Name'`, and you get the string `'categoryName'`. You then do this:

```
('categoryName').val(...);
```

This is the same as `'categoryName'.val(...)`, which obviously won't work, because strings do not have a `val` method.

You are attempting to do a jQuery selection, for which you need the jQuery constructor:

```
$(type+'Name').val('...');
```

This, of course, is also unlikely to work, unless you have elements with the tag name `categoryName`. Presumably you actually want elements with that class:

```
$('.' + type + 'Name')
```

or `id`:

```
$('#' + type + 'Name')
```

or something similar.

Comment: ya i thought about it but ן'm trying to do a function that will fit some situations and this is not the only id thet influence form that function

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and use it's returned value:

<sub>[**DEMO1**](http://jsbin.com/amOpOqOG/3/edit)       **[DEMO2](http://jsbin.com/amOpOqOG/1/edit)**</sub>

```
function type(){
  return (blabla == blublu) ? 'category' : 'regular';
}


$('[name="'+ type() +'Name"]').val('SOME VALUE');
```

If you use `ID` rather than `name` attribute:

```
function type(){
  return (blabla == blublu) ? '#category' : '#regular';
}


$( type() +'Name').val('SOME VALUE');
```

Or just simply:

```
var typeID =  blabla==blublu? '#category' : '#regular';
$( typeID +'Name').val('SOME VALUE');
```

Answer (score 0):

val() is a method provided by jquery. So to access it you will need to use the '$' operator along with the mode of selection :

```
var type = (blabla == blublu)? 'category':'regular';
```

For accessing using **ID** :

```
$("#"+type).val("...");
```

For accessing using **Class** :

```
$("."+type).val("...");
```

For accessing using any custom attribute for eg. **data** :

```
$("data['"+type+"']").val("...");
```

Answer (score -2):

You only can safely do that with an object key.

Create an object like so.

```
var obj = {
   'categoryName': ...

};
```

To retrieve it use something like this:

```
obj[someString]
```

`eval` is an option is not wise.

Comment: Do what? I'm sorry but your answer is as muddled as the question :/